# Is there size limits for repositories on a self hosted gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I have been looking around for a while but I have not found a clear answer, I am wanting to host GitLab myself for some personal projects but due to the nature of some of these projects the repository size may exceed 100GB, I know that GitLab SaaS has a repo limit of 10GB but is this limit still present in a self-hosted GitLab instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default no size limit. if you are PREMIUM user you can set it.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#repository-size-limit